# How does Vec::push work for self referencing types?

Tags: rust, self-reference

Quoted from `vec::push` implementation:

```
pub fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
    // This will panic or abort if we would allocate > isize::MAX bytes
    // or if the length increment would overflow for zero-sized types.
    if self.len == self.buf.capacity() {
        self.buf.reserve_for_push(self.len);
    }
    unsafe {
        let end = self.as_mut_ptr().add(self.len);
        ptr::write(end, value);
        self.len += 1;
    }
}
```

Here if `T` is self referencing type, how is it guaranteed after `ptr::write` there's a valid object at `end`?

Comment: How can `T` be self-referencing? To my knowledge only `Pin`ned objects can have self-references, but pinned objects are always behind a pointer and cannot be moved. If a type `U` is self-referencing then you'll only have access via a `Pin<U>` pointer (which is not self-referencing).

Answer (score 3):

In Rust, all types are movable and thus must be valid after moving; `ptr::write` essentially just moves the value to a new location.

Because of this, self-referential objects can only work by hiding behind some indirection that keeps their address stable. And you can't really guarantee something being stable unless you've used `Pin`. But regardless, the pin itself would still be movable, so passing one to `.push()` is not an issue. If a self-referencing type has an issue with `.push()`, it is an issue with that type.